# does anyone know what encryption is this?

Tags: mysql, encryption

Does anyone know what type of encryption is this:

zlnL/JLk3dtHQiKqHEpxz+Y2Y6ueKi1soF5scb1BYqpAkeBMEKsCnMB9LA1BsM+rKaOZMDBxpzJ56HXuRrQFDA==

Or a method to find out what encryption is used.
The line is taken out from a mysql db and i wanna know what contains.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That is a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. You can see it on the last two `==` that is typically for that encoding.

Comment: No, is not.If it was that simple..

Comment: It *is* base 64 without a doubt. But for all we know it can encode binary data. Unless you know the data model behind it is impossible to decode. It is not necesseraly words.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I appreciate.Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I thought is using base 64 with another encriptyon, i dont know encription methods, for me, all this are new, and i know the data behind is in this format 9887877889899898, only numbers and maybe.. an = .

Comment: The `==` are not "typical", they just happen to appear sometimes. They are padding used when the last group contains only one byte, and can be omitted as often as not.